# Removing Trailing Unit of Measure From Variable ex. "10GB" -> "10"

Tags: powershell, exchange-online

I am working on a PS script to convert an ExchangeOnline user mailbox to a shared mailbox and would like to implement a safety check. The user mailbox must be under 50GB to be converted to a shared mailbox.

```
$upn = Read-host -Prompt "Input the UPN of the user you would like to convert. ex. User@Example.com
->"
$mailboxsize = get-mailboxstatistics $upn | select TotalItemSize
```

In this instance

```
$mailboxsize
```

returns:

```
TotalItemSize
-------------
XX.X GB (XX,XXX,XXX,XXX bytes)
```

I would like to remove everything after "XX.XX" so that I can use a if/then with a comparitor to either display an error or continue the script. Tried doing some research but not really sure how to word this to get the results I'm after.

This is my first post/question apologies if its in the wrong place/etc. Let me know if I am doing something wrong with formatting or anything else.

Various -arguments
Comparing XX.X GB (XX,XXX,XXX,XXX bytes) to XX.X GB (XX,XXX,XXX,XXX bytes)

Comment: I think what you're seeing is the result of how PowerShell is formatting a custom "mailbox size" object *for display*. I don't have any Exchange cmdlets installed locally so I can't test, but various articles suggest doing this will return the value in GB: ```(get-mailboxstatistics $upn).Value.ToGB()```. HTH.

Comment: Sometimes these serialized return objects have sub values like `.Value`. If not you may use regex to catch the numbers inside the parenthesis and calulate the needed size by yourself. 

Comment: What does `Get-MailboxStatistics $upn | Get-Member` produce? I can use `[double](Get-EXOMailboxStatistics -Identity jdoe@example.com).TotalItemSize.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

@lit
The EXO command works for my application, I guess you can use .Value there but not with the Get-Mailboxstatistics cmlet. I was able to test it and it works great!

```
#Request UPN

$upn = Read-host -Prompt "Input the UPN of the user you would like to convert. ex. User@Example.com
->"


#Get mailbox TotalItemSize value

$MailboxSize = [double](Get-EXOMailboxStatistics -Identity $upn).TotalItemSize.Value


#Compare $mailboxsize against 49.99GB

if($MailboxSize -gt 49990000000){

Write-host -ForegroundColor red $upn is over 50 GB and cannot be converted to a shared mailbox.
Read-Host 'Press any key to quit'
Exit
}
```

Comment: Side note - Powershell has some built-in “multiplier” suffixes that let you say, for example ```50Gb``` instead of the constant ```53687091200``` - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_numeric_literals?view=powershell-7.4#integer-literals - you can also use it for example to convert byte counts to gb ```$sizeInGB = $sizeInBytes / 1GB``` or vice versa ```$sizeInBytes = $sizeInGb * 1GB```, and there’s other suffixes for mb, kb, etc.